# Difference Between Database Date and Today's Date

Tags: javascript, java, php, mysql, date

I am developing a website that allow user to see their equipments and know how much days passed till the repair started.

But i am having trouble getting the DATABASE information about the date.
I registered a column DATE and i made it TIMESTAMP with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP so it can automaticly atribut the date that joined the system.

I am using a script to get today's date and i put it in a table so it can show the user:

```
<script>
var days = new Date(); 
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days.toISOString().substr(0, 10); 
</script>
```

Then i called a function that gets all equipment info ( client name, DATE, Type, etc...):

```
include_once('DataAccess.php');
$da = new DataAccess();
$res = $da->getEquipmentInfo();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){
echo " <td id='days'></td> "; }
```

How do i make to calculate the difference between the database columns DATE and today's date to know how much days passed?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am using a script to get today's date and i put it in a table so it can show the user:" What kind of table? Mysql table or html table?

Comment: The script `<script>
var days = new Date(); 
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days.toISOString().substr(0, 10); 
</script>`
Is used to get today's date.

Comment: I asked what you meant by putting it in a table. I know what it does

Comment: I want the user to see their equipments like the state of the equipment, the date that it was registered etc... I just putted it on a table because of the look. I can perfectly put it in a <p> or something.

Comment: Ok so you meant and HTML table, thats all I needed to know

Comment: you have neglected to include the sql statement that fetches the data from the database - or do you intend for the date calculations to all be done in javascript/php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert both dates into unix and then find the difference between them and depending on if you want days, weeks, minutes, ect. you will have to convert. I dont have enough information for on your code and all your javascript to do it for you but here is a php example.

```
<?php
   $now = time(); 
   $db_unix = strtotime($res->theMysqlTimestamp);
   $datediff = $now - $db_unix;
   echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
?>
```

This takes the date now, your timestamp from mysql gets the unix timestamps, subtracts them, and then calculates the days difference between them.

Comment: Ok thanks. But i am new programming with PHP.
What is that $db_unix and theMysqlTimestamp?
What do i have to put on those lines of code?

I can give you all the information you want about my code.

Comment: Well I am just making assumptions since I don't know your database table structure. But what the `$db_unix` variable holds is the converted timestamp from your database table. It is converted to a unix timestamp. So the `theMysqlTimestamp` should just be your timestamp from the database. Does that make sense?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!
You resolved my problem.
I really apreciate that!

Comment: Your welcome! If you would not mind can you please accept my answer as the right one.

Comment: One more question.
I want when the admin changes the equipment state those days return to 0 and start counting again.
How do i do that?
I want when he press a button it returns to 0, like `onclick='return $now = 0'`?

Comment: Hmm, well you could do this a couple different ways, but honestly, I would just make another column in the database, one for `creation date` and one for `state change date`. Then just compare the state change column to todays date and when the state changes then update that column. This way you can keep the creation date but also track state changes.

Comment: Is there another simple way just by doing a function or something like that?
Because i didn't really understand xD
Sorry!

Comment: I guess I dont really understand then. You want this statechange timestamp to be persistent right? If you want the time to go to 0 when an admin makes a change you will have to update the database with a new timestamp when something was changed.

Comment: So i think i have to do that...
Because i want when admin changes the database  column ' state ' the days passed return to 0...